# How can I use the Mock annotation in Scala?

Tags: scala, mockito

I'm using scalatest and Scala 2.x.  The following compiles/works:

```scala
import org.mockito.Mockito._
import org.mockito._
import org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers._

class Test1 extends AnyFunSuite { 

  val action = Mockito.mock(classOf[Action])
  when(action.process(anyInt())).thenReturn("x")
  ...
}
```

This doesn't:

```scala
import org.mockito.Mockito._
import org.mockito._
import org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers._

class Test1 extends AnyFunSuite { 

  @Mock
  val action = Action()
  when(action.process(anyInt())).thenReturn("x")
  ...
}
```

I get this exception on the "when" line:

```
[info] Test1 *** ABORTED ***
[info]   org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: Misplaced or misused argument matcher detected here:
[info]
[info] -> at Test1.<init>(Test1.scala:17)
[info]
[info] You cannot use argument matchers outside of verification or stubbing.
[info] Examples of correct usage of argument matchers:
[info]     when(mock.get(anyInt())).thenReturn(null);
[info]     doThrow(new RuntimeException()).when(mock).someVoidMethod(anyObject());
[info]     verify(mock).someMethod(contains("foo"))
[info]
[info] This message may appear after an NullPointerException if the last matcher is returning an object
[info] like any() but the stubbed method signature expect a primitive argument, in this case,
[info] use primitive alternatives.
[info]     when(mock.get(any())); // bad use, will raise NPE
[info]     when(mock.get(anyInt())); // correct usage use
[info]
[info] Also, this error might show up because you use argument matchers with methods that cannot be mocked.
[info] Following methods *cannot* be stubbed/verified: final/private/equals()/hashCode().
[info] Mocking methods declared on non-public parent classes is not supported.
[info]   at Test1.<init>(Test1.scala:17)
[info]   at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
[info]   at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
[info]   at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
[info]   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
[info]   at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
[info]   at org.scalatest.tools.Framework$ScalaTestTask.execute(Framework.scala:450)
[info]   at sbt.TestRunner.runTest$1(TestFramework.scala:140)
[info]   at sbt.TestRunner.run(TestFramework.scala:155)
[info]   at sbt.TestFramework$$anon$3$$anonfun$$lessinit$greater$1.$anonfun$apply$1(TestFramework.scala:318)
[info]   ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would avoid mocking altogether, but if you actually need it, in Scala I would use something like [ScalaMock](https://scalamock.org/) which cooperates better with the language.

```scala
class Test1 extends AnyFunSuite { 

  val action = mock[Action]
  (action.process _).expects(*).returning("x")
  ...
}
```

From what I see `@Mock` annotation relies on some [custom JUnit runner](https://howtodoinjava.com/mockito/mockito-annotations/) which injects logic into test class by combining Guice/Spring-like dependency injection with mocking. But you are using it wrong:

```scala
// Here you would have to configure JUnit runner
// (but Scala test libraries are not really JUnit-based)
class Test1 extends AnyFunSuite { 

  // Here you would have to configure action as var
  // and not initialize it yourself, so that runner could
  // create the mocks and put them here using reflection
  // after instance initialization
  @Mock
  var action: Action = _

  // Here you could not have the test logic be implemented
  // as vals or vars, because it would be executed in object's
  // constructor - when action is still unititialized
  // (therefore null). JUnit doesn't show this issue as it
  // uses @Mock on class attributes, and put @Test logic in
  // methods - called only after constructor is completed
  // and JUnitRunner injects additional logic 
  // ...
}
```

You could totally do it like:

```scala
// use JUnit instead of Scalatest
@RunWith(classOf[MockitoJUnitRunner])
class Test1 {

  @Mock
  var action: Action = _

  @Test
  def example(): Unit = {
    // ...
  }
}
```

so it *is* possible to make it work in Scala, just not with the non-JUnit-based testing libraries. If you are interested in Mockito conventions in ScalaTest see [a dedicated documentation page](https://www.scalatest.org/plus/mockito).

Comment: I'd suggest to use scala mockito from [mockito](https://github.com/mockito/mockito-scala) project instead of scalatest. It supports more functionality comparing with scalatest